# Using Python to create a new Numpy array from an existing one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to use Python and Numpy to take a grayscale image (as a Numpy array), then iterate through it by pixel in order to differentiate the image in the X a direction. I can't use any functions to do this automatically, I need to iterate unfortunately.
I need to use the derivative: F(x, y) = F(x, y+1) - F(x, y) to each pixel and return the output in the form of a new image (in a Numpy array).

A simple 4 pixel example 
10 15 5 25
Would return
5 10 20

I want to take the absolute value (eliminating negative values) and have the output width be 1 column shorter than the input (since no calculation can be performed on the last column).

I can read the array using np.nditer, but I could really use some help figuring out how to apply that calculation to each element and return the results.

I figured this out in Java fairly quickly, can any of the Python gurus out there  help me convert this?

```
public class ArrayTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arrayOne = { 5, 10, 20, 5 };
    int[] newArray = new int[arrayOne.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOne.length - 1; i++) {

        newArray[i] = Math.abs(arrayOne[i + 1] - arrayOne[i]);

        System.out.println(newArray[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `np.abs(np.diff(F,axis=1))`?

Comment: Its second-order accurate rather than your requested first-order, but you could use [`np.gradient`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

Comment: I wish I could use these functions, but the requirements specify that I 'feel the pain' and iterate through each pixel. For example, Pixel a is 5 and Pixel b is 10, I need to create a new Pixel a of 5 and add to a new array...and so on.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Yes, and i'm getting too old for homework :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my snide comment about homework:

Looking at your Java code, I think this is what you want?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([10, 15, 5, 25])
diff = np.abs(data[:-1] - data[1:])

print diff
array([ 5, 10, 20])
```

EDIT:

I'm simply taking every value of the array apart from the last one (as there's nothing to be computed there) and differencing that versus every value apart from the first.

```
print data[:-1]
array([10, 15,  5])
print data[1:]
array([15,  5, 25])
```

`data[1:] - data[:-1]` is equivalent to F(x) = F(x+1) - F(x).

I imagine you're familiar with slicing notation from using lists.

Using a loop:

```
new = np.empty(shape = data.shape[0]-1)

for i in range(0, new.shape[0]):
    new[i] = np.abs(data[i+1] - data[i])
```

As @Joe Kington says, you generally shouldn't need to do this, as numpy allows using vectorised expressions (operations computed on the entire array rather than for each element), which makes the code a lot faster. Not a requirement in this trivial example, but would probably give you noticeable benefits if you're doing this with lots of large arrays.

EDIT 2:

Using a loop in the 2D case:

```
import numpy as np
data =  np.array([10, 15, 5, 25])
data_2d = np.repeat(data,2).reshape(-1,2) #make some 2d data
data_2d[:,1] = data_2d[:,1] + 100 #make the y axis different so we can tell them apart easier

print data_2d
[[ 10 110]
 [ 15 115]
 [  5 105]
 [ 25 125]]

'''
Making a new array to store the results, copying over the Y values.
The X values we will change later. Note that not using the .copy() 
method would create a VIEW of data_2d, so when we change new,
data_2d would change as well.
'''

new = data_2d[:-1,:].copy()

print new.shape
(3,2) # 3 here is the number of elements per axis, 2 is the number of axes. 

for i in range(0,data_2d.shape[0]-1): # looping the X axis
   new[i,0] = np.abs(data_2d[i+1,0] - data_2d[i,0]) # referencing the X axis explicitly

print new
[[  5 110]
 [ 10 115]
 [ 20 105]]
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. If that is returning 5,10,20 then that is basically what i'm looking for, although I don't quite understand it yet. Does a for loop not need to be included? In my limited experience with python, I would iterate the array with np.nditer and follow that with a for loop.

Comment: @yodish - You can use a loop, but its typically an anti-pattern when dealing with numpy arrays.  It will be much faster to use vectorized expressions.  Regardless, you wouldn't want `np.nditer` in this case.  If you were going to iterate through, use indexing just like you would in your Java example.

Comment: @yodish - I edited my answer with some explanation, plus an example of how this'd look like using a loop. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for breaking that down, it's making a little more sense to me. So, in my case, where i'm taking an 'image' (a numpy array), performing calculations, and returning 'new_image' (another numpy array); using your loop example, would I just replace 'data' with 'image' and 'new' with 'new_image'? I apologize for not testing this myself, I don't have python installed on my work machine and admin rights are so elusive...

Comment: It'd be in 2D so `new_image` would need to be a 2D array and you'd need to refer to the values on the X axis explicitly when you're looping over it.

Comment: I also need to do this in regards to the Y axis as well, so i'm glad you brought that up. Referring to the values on the X axis explicitly would entail editing the `range(0, new.shape[0]):` statement, correct?

Comment: I've added an example in the 2D case using a loop, since you insist that that's what's required. I hope this helps. If you feel I've addressed your question adequately, feel free to accept my answer :).

Comment: areuexperienced, I really appreciate the time you're taking. Your first code  snippet is getting me the closest to the image I need to return, however it's width is still 1 short. When I try both of your loop examples, I am returning something way off. I may be doing something wrong though. I found this sample, which returns what I need; I just don't know how to convert it into loop form `new = np.array(data[:,1:data.shape[1]],dtype=float)-data[:,0:data.shape[1]-1]`

Comment: I really can't do much else without seeing an example

Comment: I understand, and I think it's possible the solution is simpler than my convoluted explanation led you to believe. I need to iterate through a 2D array and evaluate each pixel column by column, applying `image[r,c] = image[r,c+1] - image[r,c]` to each pixel. I then return a new updated 2D array. I also need to create a separate function that iterates through a similar 2D array, except this time I need to subtract rows 'image[r,c] = image[r+1,c] - image[r,c]` and return the a new updated 2D array.

Comment: I haven't quite figured out if I need to create a 'new' array to load the altered pixel values into or if I can just alter the existing array on the fly. I'm also struggling with the syntax and the logic. For example, how to properly reference the +1 element. Very frustrating; especially given the various functions out there that will do this automatically :)

Comment: If you'll be making an array that's 1 column smaller than the original, then you won't be able to alter the existing one, as the shapes won't match. Also, I think it's best practice not to alter your data from under you unless you really know what you're doing. I feel your pain, but I guess that's what the point of the learning exercise is :).

Comment: Good advice, thank you areuexperienced. I appreciate your help.